# Retrieve html across domains using jQuery and JSONP

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have a form that outputs one simple line of html `<a href="link">A LINK</a>`

I can access the process directly with data appended to the url like http://site.com/form.asp?sample=100

Because this is going across domains (to a subdomain) I am trying to do this using JSONP.  I first tried it with datatype json but I was still getting a 403 forbidden.  Here is what I am trying with JSONP but this is all kinds of messed up and returns an error with this %5Bobject%20Object%5D" appended to it.  I guess it is a problem with how I am trying to append the data to the url ?

```
$j.getJSON({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://site.com/form.asp',
        data: 'order=' + ordervalue,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSONP doesn't work like this, you're not sending JSON at all, you're sending HTML.

JSONP is strictly a GET request (made by creating a `<script>` tag), you cannot POST cross-domain *and* get the result back...it just doesn't work that way.  The way JSONP works is it basically adds this to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.com/form.asp?order=something&callback=myFunc"></script>
```

....that response has to be valid JavaScript, typically it looks like:

```
myFunc({ "key": "value"...data, etc... });
```

It doesn't work for fetching HTML, it just throws a syntax error, this limitation is *very* intentional, and part of the security blocks in place (part of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).

Comment: thanks for the explanation Nick.  I did have type set as 'GET' but was having the same problem so thought I would try post.  Do you have a recommendation about how to grab the html that is printed from a url with properties across domain? I was close using json but get the 403 and I do not know if I am very close with the jsonp.

Comment: @zac - You would have to proxy the request through your own domain if you want to fetch HTML, you can only fetch JavaScript cross-domain

Comment: Can we send the tag somehow in encoded format in the JSON returned?

Answer (score 1):

You can still post/get cross domain on the client:

**flyJSONP/YQL

jankyPOST/postMessage/contentWindow

CORS**