# Why does this ajax call fail?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, cross-domain

I'm on http://www.mywebsite.com, and I do a cross-domain ajax call (with jQuery) to http://myownajax.projects.it/folder/mypage.aspx :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myownajax.projects.it/folder/mypage.aspx ',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

where it easily print "Hello" :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="mypage.aspx.cs" Inherits="folder_mypage" %>

Hello
```

but in fact I get an 200 OK error. Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross site scripting (aka XSS) is blocked by browsers as it is a security risk.

If you must retrieve data from another URL, you must use the JSONP format and `GET` requests only.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myownajax.projects.it/folder/mypage.aspx',
    type: 'get', // this is optional as 'get' is the default.
    datatype: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: It said "Hello is not defined" : I need a conversion to JSON? Or what?

Comment: How are you accessing the variable? I assume the code you are using is not the same as you have posted as you would get a different error.

Comment: Change your .aspx page to return a string which can be parsed into JSON format, in your example this would be `["Hello"]`

Comment: Uhm, in fact I need to send a whole page to the client! How can I do?

Comment: I get `parsererror - SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier`

Comment: That is not possible with cross-site requests. Only JSON formatted data can be sent/received.

Comment: "because on the real example I've <div class="myClass">, that's why! How can I encode it?

Comment: Ok! So I need to insert into an JSON a string (which is my html). How can I do it?

Comment: It's best to open another question for that - don't forget to mark this one as accepted though ;)

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the `dataType:"jsonp"`, and cross domain ajax only support `type:"GET"`. `type:"POST"` is not allowed.

Comment: It works! Now I get "Hello is not defined". I think I need a conversion?

Comment: It is not possible to fetch HTML from other domain. [FYR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265037/retrieve-html-across-domains-using-jquery-and-jsonp)